# How to write a constraint in Cplex

Tags: constraints, cplex

I have load nodes `n`. There are three lines connected at each load node `n`. A variable `x` is defined for each line. I have to write a constraint in such a way that the range of variable `x` value lies between `0.5<=x<=1` for one of three lines and for the rest of two lines its range is in between `0<=x<=0.5`. it may also happen that the value of this variable for all three lines lies between the range `0<=x<=0.5`. Suggest to me how to write this constraint in OPL CPLEX.

The code that I am trying

```
forall (n in threeline_node){ 
 
forall (l in Line:lineconect[l].tonode == n) {

  0.5+ 1e-6<=alpha[l]<=1;              // but this code is not correct.

}

}
```

Comment: at least one line connected to each load node falls in the range

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hasLineInUpperRange && hasLineInLowerRange) {

} else if (hasLineInUpperRange) {
    // All lines should be in the upper range
    forall (l in linesConnectedToNode) {
        0.5 <= alpha[l] <= 1;
    }
} else {
    forall (l in linesConnectedToNode) {
        0 <= alpha[l] <= 0.5;
    }
}
```

}

In this code decalare bool and values  hasLineInLowerRange ,hasLineInUpperRange   are false

Answer (score 0):

Logical constraints could help:

```
range nodes=1..4;
range lines=1..3;


dvar float+ x[nodes][lines] in 0..1;

dexpr int nbInRange[n in nodes]=sum(l in lines) (0<=x[n][l]<=0.5);


subject to
{
  forall(n in nodes) nbInRange[n]>=2;
}
```